# how to create GET form in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, kannel

So what i want is . to have a form that when i click submit, it gives me output like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing?text='testing'&number=1234564
```

not the usual

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing/key:value
```

it's for Kannel , and it only works with GET forms.

**Update**

Now Kannel works in GET post as i mentioned. but as Tyler said. it should work behind the scene so that no one just use the SMS feature and send whatever they want.

here is how it works, assuming the username is tester and password is foobar ( it's in the smskannel.conf file ) , these two lines send the sms when kannel is configured and running in the background ( Locally )

```
$url = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=0127715667&text='This is the Message'";
$urloutput=file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to allow any form on your site directly pass through Kannel?

I would suggest submitting the form to your application as a POST, constructing the URL in the action, and then doing whatever it is you want to do with Kannel. (I'm not very familiar with Kannel)

Comment: you are right. I need to work behind the scene .. I found out how i will post it in the question .

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
echo $form->create('Model',  array('type' => 'get'));
```

To go to another website:

echo $form->create(Null,  array('type' => 'get', 'url' => 'http://www.google.com/search'));

Comment: yeah it works .. but my problem was I wanted to have a tottaly different url .. instead of my website in the url .. go to a different website with the form data. 

then again as tyler said. I need to make it work behind the scene. 

however thank you very much